# Duplicate entry '' for key 2

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

Here is the php code that gives me "Duplicate entry '' for key 2" error...

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "admin"; 
$pass = "123";
$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die (mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."<BR>");

    $userid=  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userid']);
$latitude=  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['latitude']);
$longitude=  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['longitude']);
//$time=  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['time']);


$db_select=mysql_select_db("new");
if(!$db_select){
    die(mysql_error());
    echo "error";
}

$query= "INSERT INTO location(Userid, Latitude, Longitude )
VALUES ('{$userid}', '{$latitude}', '{$longitude}'); " ;

if($medo=mysql_query($query)){
    header("localhost/filename");
    exit;
}else{
    echo"<p> Error</p>";
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

I don't think there is a problem with my code. please help.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: The problem is, I don't have enough time to learn or even change my code. Is there a solution to this problem? A shortcut maybe?

Comment: This error means, thar you have `PRIMARY KEY` duplicates for ID column, OR duplicate for columns, which is part of [`UNIQUE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) index. Check table for duplicates. Consider using [`INSERT INGNORE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html), or [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///replace.html).

Comment: i am  afraid .. you need to learn and that is proper solution ... and pdo and mysqli_* is as simple as mysql_*

Comment: Usually user id should always be unique so I assume that is the unique column in your SQL table. In this case one of the variables you are inserting are already in your database table (and the column of that variable has a unique key). Following up with the assumption that the userid is the collision maybe try inputting a different ID, or don't allow users to enter their ID and just have that column increment automatically.

Comment: Can you do a "SHOW CREATE TABLE location" in MySQL and past the result here?

Answer (score 0):

As I suppose you'll want to update if already present, use this syntax for your MySQL request :

```
$query= "INSERT INTO location (Userid, Latitude, Longitude )
VALUES ('{$userid}', '{$latitude}', '{$longitude}') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Latitude='{$latitude}', Longitude='{$longitude}';";
```

So that when your user already exist, it will be updated with the new coordinates

Answer (score 0):

if the user_id is primary key make it auto increment and don,t post this value from front end.

if it is not a primary key than it will be definitely a unique key. so before insertion first check that record already exists or not.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the unique record for each user, you have to check if user record already exists, then use UPDATE instead of INSERT.

If there are many records for each user, just remove PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY from 'Userid' column.

Comment: Just like "ruin you database" if you don't know "how it works" or "why it works so". Downvoted.

Comment: I think you just misunderstood what I mean. If there is a need to store multiple coordinates for each user, one must remove 'primary key'. For example: [user1: 23,83],[user1: 83,28]